# Or operator between two commands fails?

Tags: shell-script, shell

[image]
I am trying to add a usage statement for users don't run this bash script with any filenames. I thought I could use the "OR" operator. But the script still failed.

```
#! /bin/bash
file="$1"
sort -k3,3 -k2,2 -k1 "$1" | awk '{ sum=0; for(i=4; i<=NF; i++){sum+=$i}; sum/=NF-3; print int(sum),"["$1"]",$3",",$2}' || echo "Usage: GradesAwk.sh filename"
```

And here is the sample data.

```
123456789 Lee Johnson 72 85 90
999999999 Jaime Smith 90 92 91
888111818 JC Forney 100 81 97
290010111 Terry Lee 100 99 100
199144454 Tracey Camp 77 84 84
299226663 Laney Camp 70 74 71
434401929 Skyler Camp 78 81 82
928441032 Jess Forester 85 80 82
928441032 Chris Forester 97 94 89
```

Comment: Do you seriously think it is a good idea to offer a screen shot instead of pasting the code into your question?

Comment: Please paste the code in a a code syntax, not a screenshot.

Comment: Well, that’s a good start, but your question doesn't really make much sense unless you show (or explain) that it doesn’t give the error message you want it to give when it’s invoked with no arguments. (In this case that’s even more important than the input data, but, as long as you’ve got them in the question, you might as well leave them in.)

Answer (score 1):

What you get is typical bash behavior, due to pipefail option (disabled by default).

Bash manual refers:

> The return status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last
>   command, unless the pipefail option is enabled.If pipefail is enabled,
>   the pipeline's return status is the value of the last (rightmost)
>   command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands exit
>   successfully.

In your case, the sort command fails, but the awk command does not fail;it just receives no input and this is not a failure for awk.

As a result your `||` branch is not executed since with pipefail disabled (default) the last pipeline command (awk) was successfull.

All you need is to include `set -o pipefail` in your script to enable pipefail.

Check this test out:

```
$ ls file7*
file7

$ sort file7 |awk '{print $1}' || echo "error"
abc
four
klm

$  sort file77 |awk '{print $1}' || echo "error"
sort: cannot read: file77: No such file or directory

$ sort file77 2>/dev/null |awk '{print $1}' || echo "error"

$ set -o pipefail

$ sort file77 2>/dev/null |awk '{print $1}' || echo "error"
error
```

Comment: Or better yet, test whether a (exactly one) parameter is specified, and whether it exists (is a file), and whether it is readable, ***before*** trying to run a command with the parameter as input.

Comment: Thanks, George! And does the "sort fail warning" will always show up even my script is now runnable and gives output to the echo command?

Comment: @user251505 you can hide the sort failure message by applying `2>/dev/null` at the end of sort command, like my test.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do your validation as early as possible:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="$1"

if [[ -z "$file" ]]; then
    echo "Error: no file provided." >&2
    echo "usage: $0 file" >&2
    exit 1

elif [[ ! -f "$file" ]]; then
    echo "Error: no such file '$file'" >&2
    exit 2
fi

sort ... "$file" | awk ...
```